# Can't divide by zero Fractions

Tags: java, math

So I had have a simple application for school. Which does subtracting, dividing, multiplying and adding on fractions.

It worked quite good, but now with 1 fraction I'm getting an error.
Fraction: 28/16 - 42/24

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
at sample.Breuk.reduce(Breuk.java:70)
at sample.Breuk.subtract(Breuk.java:44)
at sample.Main.main(Main.java:15)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

So i went to the line where it goes wrong and it turned out it was at subtracting the fraction.

Now I calculated the fraction (28/16 - 42/24) and the result = 0.

So I know where my bug is and what is going wrong, but I don't know how to fix this. Anybody having some tips for me?

```
    public Breuk subtract(Breuk other){
    int d = teller * other.teller;
    int n1 = noemer * other.teller;
    int n2 = other.noemer * teller;
    Breuk b = new Breuk(n1-n2,d);
    b.reduce();
    return b;
}

    private void reduce() {
        int i = Math.min(Math.abs(noemer), Math.abs(teller));
           if (i == 0) {
               System.out.println("Error");
           }
           while ((noemer % i != 0) || (teller % i != 0)) //BUG IS HERE//
               i--;
           noemer = noemer / i;
           teller = teller / i;
    }
}
```

MAIN:

```
  Breuk a = new Breuk(28,16);
  Breuk b = new Breuk(42,24);
  Breuk g = a.subtract(b); // Breuk A - Breuk b
  System.out.println(a + " - " + b + " = "+ g);
```

Comment: When you `% i` or `/ i`, check if `i` is not 0. If so, handle it (you decide how).

Comment: You have a `Breuk(0, 384)`, i.e. `i` starts out as `0`. You probably print the "error" (which is not really an error in this case), but then continue anyways. If the `noemer` is `0`, you should just reduce to `0/1`.

Comment: @tobias_k yes that is true, so I just have to change the if to reduce it and make the while in a else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of the subtraction is `Breuk(0, 384)`, i.e. in `reduce`, `i` starts out as `0`. You print the "error" (which is not really an error in this case), but then continue anyways.

It seems like, in `reduce` you are trying to calculate the [greatest common divisor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) by starting with `i` as the lower of `noemer` and `teller` and reducing it until it is a divisor of both. But this will fail if one of the two is `0`, as in the case of `Breuk(0, 384)`. To get this case correct, you'd have to start with the *higher* of the two, as `0 % 384 == 0`, but `384 % 0 == ERROR`, i.e.

```
    int i = Math.max(Math.abs(noemer), Math.abs(teller));
```

Alternatively, you could just use [Euclid's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Using_Euclid.27s_algorithm) to get the greatest common divisor.

```
private void reduce() {
    int gcd = gcd(noemer, teller);
    noemer /= gcd;
    teller /= gcd;
}

private int gcd(int a, int b) {
    return b == 0 ? a : gcd(b, a % b);
}
```

Both will correctly reduce the fraction `0/384` to `0/1` and, e.g., `6/14` to `3/7`

Comment: Perfect! this is working. Could u elaborate a bit more on the int gcd(a,b) how it works